# How can I add a transition between activities in this code structure?

Tags: java, android

I have a code structure. What is necessary for me to transfer the screen of death in this, that is, the screen after the character dies, to another java file. I've been working on this but couldn't find it. I created a new java file, when the character dies, I want to go to that screen and show the score there.

It's a flappy bird style game. The character dies when hitting incoming creatures. When it dies, I want to redirect it to a new fragment and create a structure there such as score and try again. This is the only code snippet.

```
package com.nejdetkadirr.survivorbird;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Circle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector;

import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JColorChooser;

public class SurvivorBird extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture background;
    Texture bird;
    Texture ufo1;
    Texture ufo2;
    Texture ufo3;
    float birdY=0;
    float birdX=0;
    int gameStart = 0;
    float velocity = 0; //Fast
    float ufoVelocity = 5; //Fast
    float gravity = 0.4f;
    int intNumberofUfo = 4;
    int score=0;
    int scoredUfo = 0;
    Random random;
    Circle birdCircle;
    ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    BitmapFont font;
    float[] ufoX = new float[intNumberofUfo];
    float[] ufoOfset1 = new float[intNumberofUfo];
    float[] ufoOfset2 = new float[intNumberofUfo];
    float[] ufoOfset3 = new float[intNumberofUfo];
    float distance = 0;
    Circle[] ufoCircles1;
    Circle[] ufoCircles2;
    Circle[] ufoCircles3;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        background = new Texture("background.png");
        bird = new Texture("bird.png");
        ufo1 = new Texture("ufo.png");
        ufo2 = new Texture("ufo.png");
        ufo3 = new Texture("ufo.png");
        birdY=Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2;
        birdX=Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/4;
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        font.getData().setScale(4);
        birdCircle = new Circle();
        ufoCircles1 = new Circle[intNumberofUfo];
        ufoCircles2 = new Circle[intNumberofUfo];
        ufoCircles3 = new Circle[intNumberofUfo];

        distance = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2;
        random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < intNumberofUfo; i++) {
            ufoOfset1[i] = (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 200);
            ufoOfset2[i] = (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 200);
            ufoOfset2[i] = (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 200);


            ufoX[i] = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - ufo1.getWidth() / 2 + i * distance;
            ufoCircles1[i] = new Circle();
            ufoCircles3[i] = new Circle();
            ufoCircles2[i] = new Circle();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        batch.begin();

        //Draw background
        batch.draw(background,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        if (gameStart == 1) {

            if (ufoX[scoredUfo] < birdX) {
                score++;
                if (scoredUfo < intNumberofUfo-1) {
                    scoredUfo++;
                } else {
                    scoredUfo=0;
                }
            }


            if (birdY >= Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/13) {
                birdY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/13;
                velocity+=gravity;
                birdY-=velocity;
            }

            if(Gdx.input.justTouched() && birdY < Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/13) {

                    velocity-=8;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < intNumberofUfo; i++) {
                if (ufoX[i] < 0) {
                    ufoX[i]+=intNumberofUfo*distance;
                    ufoOfset1[i] = (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 200);
                    ufoOfset2[i] = (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 200);
                    ufoOfset2[i] = (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 200);
                } else {
                    ufoX[i] -= ufoVelocity;
                }
                    batch.draw(ufo1,ufoX[i],Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2  + ufoOfset1[i],Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/13,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/10);
                    batch.draw(ufo2,ufoX[i],Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2  + ufoOfset2[i],Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/13,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/10);
                    batch.draw(ufo3,ufoX[i],Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2  + ufoOfset3[i],Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/13,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/10);

                    ufoCircles1[i] = new Circle(ufoX[i]+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/26,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2  + ufoOfset1[i] +Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/20,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/26);
                    ufoCircles2[i] = new Circle(ufoX[i]+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/26,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2  + ufoOfset2[i] +Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/20,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/26);
                    ufoCircles3[i] = new Circle(ufoX[i]+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/26,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2  + ufoOfset3[i] +Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/20,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/26);
            }



            if (birdY > 0) {
                velocity+=gravity;
                birdY-=velocity;
            } else {
                gameStart=2;
            }

        } else if (gameStart == 0){
            if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
                gameStart = 1;
            }
        } else if (gameStart == 2) {
            if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
                gameStart = 1;
                birdY=Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2;
                for (int i = 0; i < intNumberofUfo; i++) {
                    ufoOfset1[i] = (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 200);
                    ufoOfset2[i] = (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 200);
                    ufoOfset2[i] = (random.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 200);


                    ufoX[i] = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - ufo1.getWidth() / 2 + i * distance;
                    ufoCircles1[i] = new Circle();
                    ufoCircles3[i] = new Circle();
                    ufoCircles2[i] = new Circle();

                }

                velocity=0;
                scoredUfo=0;
                score=0;
            } else {
                font.draw(batch,"Game over! If you want to try again you can touch to screen :)",100,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
            }
        }



        //Draw bird
        batch.draw(bird,birdX,birdY,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/13,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/10);
        font.draw(batch,"Score : " + String.valueOf(score),100,200);
        batch.end();
        birdCircle.set(birdX+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/26,birdY+Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/20,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/26);
        /*
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        shapeRenderer.circle(birdCircle.x,birdCircle.y,birdCircle.radius);
        */
        for (int i = 0; i < intNumberofUfo; i++) {
            /*
            shapeRenderer.circle(ufoX[i]+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/26,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2  + ufoOfset1[i] +Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/20,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/26);
            shapeRenderer.circle(ufoX[i]+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/26,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2  + ufoOfset2[i] +Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/20,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/26);
            shapeRenderer.circle(ufoX[i]+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/26,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2  + ufoOfset3[i] +Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/20,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/26);
            */
            if (Intersector.overlaps(birdCircle,ufoCircles1[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(birdCircle,ufoCircles2[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(birdCircle,ufoCircles3[i])) {
                gameStart = 2;
                //System.out.println("collision detection");
            }
        }
        //shapeRenderer.end();

    }
    
    @Override
    public void dispose () {

    }
}
```

exactly I want to add a transition here.how should i do it?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DashBoardActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

```js
font.draw(batch,"Game over! If you want to try again you can touch to screen :)",100,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
```

Comment: This sentence doesn't make much sense to me `What is necessary for me to transfer the screen of death in this, that is, the screen after the character dies, to another java file` Your objective here isn't entirely clear given the code you've supplied, is this your own code?

Answer (score 0):

add this in your animation folder.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DashBoardActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_out_right);
```

enter_from_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

enter_from_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```